# Storing image as stream in database - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, stream

I want to save image as stream in SQL database, I have doing that in silverlight as:

```
 OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
 if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
 {
     Stream stream = fd.File.OpenRead();
     byte[] binaryImage = new byte[stream.Length];
     stream.Read(binaryImage, 0, (int)stream.Length);

     BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
     bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
     _business.PersonalPhoto = binaryImage;
 }
```

With WPF this code does not work, fd.File does not exist.
How can I correct this code to work on WPF

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use StreamReader instead?

Comment: If all you want is just to load an image file and then store the (binary) file contents, all you need is `_business.PersonalPhoto = File.ReadAllBytes(fd.FileName);`. No need for a BitmapImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved this, here is the code for store the image in database as binary :

To store the image:

```
       Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog fd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            ILogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fd.FileName));

            Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fd.FileName);
            binaryImage = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(binaryImage, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        }

        _merchantInfo.Logo = binaryImage;
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks for everyone helped me :)

Comment: So this is the answer for the question here, or the other, or perhaps both? Should the other question be marked as duplicate again?

Comment: I cant not write the answer in the other question because it marked as duplicate :(, It closed

Comment: @Clemens, I answers both questions

Answer (score 1):

You might change your code as follow

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog  fd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ();
    if (fd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fd.FileName);
        byte[] binaryImage = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(binaryImage, 0, (int)stream.Length);

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        _business.PersonalPhoto = binaryImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the FileName property of the OpenFileDialog instead:

```
Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fd.FileName);
```